# Angular 2 retrieve text box values

Tags: angular

How to retrieve the multiple text Box's values using Id while submit in angular 2 .

For example:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let dummydata of data;let i=index"  ><input type="text" #dummyid{{I}}/>
</ul>

<button (click)="getalltextbox()"></button>
```

How to get all text box values while click button.

Comment: Perhaps wrap this in a form, assign unique name to them and catch the values from the form instead. One possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you put your data in a form, with unique names, using the index of the each object in array.

Let's say your array looks like this:

```
dummyDatas = [
  {
    name: 'first dummy',
    content: 'first'
  },  
  {
    name: 'second dummy',
    content: 'second'
  },  
  {
    name: 'third dummy',
    content: 'third'
  },  
]
```

So something like this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getalltextbox(myForm.value)">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let dummydata of data;let i=index">
      <input name="dummyData{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="dummydata.content"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

When clicking button, you would get all your input values in an object, from which you can extract the values and do whatever you like:

```
getalltextbox(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: @rajamaha was this a solution that worked for you? :)